# Forward declaring a class in a UI file

Tags: qt

I just wondered if there was a way to forward-declare a class in a Qt UI file. The issue that I have is that I use (the same version of) a same widget in two different projects : a project that uses the widget and an independant project that allows me to do testing with this widget while I'm working on its features.

Now, what happens is that when `uic` generates the `ui_widget.h` file, it adds this in it:

```
#include "widgets/custom_line_edit.h"
```

That's the include path for one of my promoted widgets. The thing is that the path to this file is not the same on the "real" project, as it should be

```
#include "modules/this_module/widgets/custom_line_edit.h"
```

I don't really know what to do not to have to edit my UI file each time to match my "current" project's file organization.

I've found [this](https://doc.qt.io/archives/3.3/designer-manual-16.html#1-8) which was quite satisfying:

> It is sometimes necessary to forward declare classes, particularly if code is being written in .ui.h files within Qt Designer. Each forward declaration is listed as it should appear in the generated C++ code.
>
> ````
> <forwards>
>    <forward>class QStringList;</forward>
> </forwards>```
> ````

But unfortunately this documentation is quite old (Qt 3.3) and the syntax seems not to work anymore - I get an Error 1.

What are my options here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue isn't one of forward declarations. I've never seen that "forward" mechanism in a UI file, but even it still works somehow, all that it does is put "class QStringList;" (or whatever) in the include file that uic generates. If you look at those include files, they will have "new SomeWidget ()" statements, and you can't create an object without its full declaration, so a forward declaration for something the UI file creates isn't helpful.

The UI definition needs the include file where the widget is defined for exactly that reason. It has to include the class definition in the file generated from uic, and the relationship between where the files reside is going to have to be consistent.

What I would do to solve this is put the widget(s) in a library, and then reference the library from my main application and my test application. Then the uic generation happens within the library, not the applications, and within the library, the relative locations of the files will remain constant. The applications don't need access to the .ui file nor the generated include file, so how the application source files are laid out in folders won't matter.

I don't see any other way to do this.

Comment: You're absolutely right. Thanks for the insightful answer.